# python - appengine image api error

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

```
def embedd_image():
    from google.appengine.api import images

    img1 = images.Image('/home/ubuntu/a.png')  // Here I am getting **error
    img2 = images.Image('/home/ubuntu/text.png')   // Here I am getting **error                                                                                                                                 
    composite = images.composite([(img1, 0, 0, 1.0, images.TOP_LEFT), (img2, 81, 25, 1.0, images.TOP_LEFT)], 144, 68,  output_encoding=0)                          
    return composite
```

** error is `Unrecognized image format`

Comment: You won't be able to access files outside your app's root directory on App Engine - after all, how would the deployed app access your home directory? Also, when you post these questions, please include the complete exception stacktrace, not just a paraphrase of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/imageclass.html):

> `class Image(image_data=None, blob_key=None)`
>
> ...
>
> `image_data` The image data, **as a bytestring** (str). The image
>   data can be encoded in JPEG, PNG, WEBP, GIF (including animated), BMP,
>   TIFF, or ICO format.

as a bytestring:

```
img1 = images.Image(open('/home/ubuntu/a.png').read())
```